# Find the density function $X+Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ have a joint density $f(x,y)=\lambda^2\exp(-\lambda y)$.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, marginal-distribution

> Find the density function $X+Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ have a joint density $f(x,y)=\lambda^2e^{-\lambda y}$ for $0\leq x \leq y, \lambda >0 $.

I used the Density transformation theorem to find the joint density of $g(s,t)= \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda t}$.

Then I find the marginal density $g(s)= \int g(s,t) dt$ where $s= x + y$, and $t = y$.

However, I struggle with two things:

1. How to determine the range of $g(s,t)$ function?
2. How to determine the lower and upper boundry pf the integral?

Comment: Why do you need the range of the density?

Comment: @orange is that not the "right way" to always write a density together with its range? Also, if i am not mistaken, the two question are related. The boundaries of the integral can be determined from the range of the distribution? Of course, I am asking this questions because i dont know any better

Comment: Well, for the range, the function is independent of $x$ and is continuous. So get the limit for $y\to 0$ and $y\to \infty$.

Comment: But again, you integrate over the domain and not the range.

Comment: What is the relation between f(x,y) and g(s,t) and X and Y?

Comment: What is $S$? What is $T$?

Comment: s = x + y, t=y...

Comment: "is that not the "right way" to always write a density together with its range?" Indeed, and this is why the writing in your title, say, is misleading. You should get used to write PDFs correctly, that is, their range included, here, $$f(x,y)=\lambda^2e^{-\lambda y}\mathbf 1_{0<x<y}$$ and the rest of your questions becomes automatically trivial...

Answer (score 0):

The pdf of $Z:=X+Y$ is $$\int_{0\le x\le y}\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y}\delta (x+y-z)dxdy=\int_{z/2}^z\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y}dy=\lambda (e^{-\lambda z/2}-e^{-\lambda z})$$for $z=0$. (Note this is clearly a pdf.) I'll explain the steps below.

First we write down an integral using the $\delta$ function; then we integrate out $x$, which only retains value of $y$ for which $x+y-z$ is negative when $x=0$ but positive when $x=y$, so that the integral is around the delta peak. These constraints can be stated as $y\le z\le 2y$, or equivalently $y/2\le z\le y$.